# UIButton inside tableview cell change text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

Well i know these types of questions are answered by SO before, but mine is little different so please read it.

I am using a button inside tableview cell. On click of button i am showing an AlertViewController with list of actions. On selecting action my button text and my custom model class propery is changed.

Button text is changing on button click. But my problem is cell not storing button state. If i change button of 1st cell and then click on second cell button all other buttons back to its default text.

[please see this video](http://recordit.co/Ubl9HekuTW)

Here is my code

setting cell data

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dbColumns", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomColumnTableViewCell

        let column = columns[indexPath.row]
        cell.dbColumnName.text = column.name
        cell.dbColumnOrder.titleLabel?.text = column.order
        cell.dbColumnOrder.tag = indexPath.row

        print(columns)
        cell.dbColumnOrder.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.showAlert(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
```

Action on button click

```
//MARK:Show Alert
    func showAlert(sender:UIButton){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Column Order", message: "Please select column order", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        let index = sender.tag
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "None", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in
            //execute some code when this option is selected
            self.columns[index].order = "None"
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Assending", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in
            //execute some code when this option is selected
            self.columns[index].order = "Assending"
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Desending", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in
            //execute some code when this option is selected
            self.columns[index].order = "Desending"
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Please hemp me.

Comment: could you maybe show what is the exact problem on a screenshot or gif? I am having a hard time understand what could be the problem.

Comment: @dirtydanee i have added a link please visit it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method Set button text like this way
First remove this

```
cell.dbColumnOrder.titleLabel?.text = column.order
```

Replace this

```
cell.dbColumnOrder.setTitle("\(column.order)", for: .normal)
```

And one more thing you need to increase `cell.dbColumnOrder` width.

Hope it works

Comment: thnx a lot....you saved my life....its working like a charm....can you please explain me what is defence between your code and mine...technically

Comment: You always need to specify ControlState when updating button's title!